# limit with absolute value in denominator

Tags: limits

I know that there are two scenarios where you use $(4-v)$ when $v\geq 4$ and $-(4-v)$ when $v<4$. But what is the answer and why/how?

$$\lim_{v\to 4^+}\frac{4-v}{|4-v|}$$

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stack Exchange.  What have you tried? Can you use the proper formatting? (See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: what is the relationship between $x$ and $v$?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I've cleaned up your post and improved it's formatting, but I still find it confusing. Do you mean the limit as $v\to 4^+$?

Comment: My bad. I am new to this site as you can tell. I meant "v" instead of "x". I don't understand why you switched it from "4-v" to "v-4"??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $v \rightarrow 4^+$ implies that we consider $v > 4$.

$$\lim_{v \rightarrow 4^+} \frac{4-v}{|4-v|}=\lim_{v \rightarrow 4^+} \frac{4-v}{v-4}=-1$$

Answer (score 0):

$v \to 4^+$ means that

$v=4+ |h|$ with $h\to 0$.

the limit becomes

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {-|h|}{|h|}=-1$$

Comment: I am confused even further. The numerator would be left alone and the denominator would become just 4-v correct? And wouldn't the answer be 1?

Comment: $v $ goes to $4$ from the right. this means that $v $ is greater than $4$. so $4-v $ is negative. its absolute value is its opposit.